# How to make the node keep a distance not overlapping in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

The networkx nodes are overlapped. How to make the node keep a distance not overlapping in networkx? In addition, I want to change size of nodes according to the associated number not the same size.

```
import networkx as nx 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

author_net = pd.read_csv('net_data.csv',encoding='utf-8')
GA = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(author_net, source="author1", target="author2")

plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
nx.draw(GA, node_size=400, alpha=0.7)
```

DATA IS ON: https://github.com/workload/my_networkx/blob/master/net_data.csv

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the actual graph, or just its plotted representation? How are you generating these images? How are you getting/creating the graph itself?

Comment: Here's a question that deals a bit with setting each node to have its own size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524177/networkx-node-sizes?rq=1

Comment: It's an actual graph, and code is updated. Need help. @heltonbiker

Comment: What about saving the graph as a .dot file and then generating the actual graph with graphviz? Would you know how to do that? Would it be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Joel, thanks, It works..

Comment: Graphviz is great. I am learning...TKS..@heltonbiker